# Tastypie error in POST and PUT for foreign key : add() argument after * must be a sequence

Tags: tastypie

**I am getting the following error message while trying to run a CURL with POST and PUT: 
{"error_message": "add() argument after * must be a sequence, not Task"**

1) *This is the command I am trying:*

```
$ curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST --data '{"tex
t":"create project plan","creator":"/user/user/2/"}' http://127.0.0.1:8000/task/
task/
```

2) *These are my ModelResources: (Task and User are the two models with FK relation)*

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    tasks=fields.OneToManyField('challenge.api.TaskResource','tasks')
    class Meta:
        allowed_methods = ['get','delete','post']
        authorization= Authorization()
        queryset = User.objects.select_related().all()        
        include_resource_uri = False        
        filtering = {
            'user_id': ALL
        }    
class TaskResource(ModelResource):
    creator=fields.ForeignKey('task.api.UserResource','creator',related_name='tasks')
    class Meta:
        allowed_methods = ['get','post','put']
        authorization= Authorization()
        queryset=Task.objects.select_related().all()
        include_resource_uri = False
        fields = ['text']
        excludes = ['id']                
        filtering = {
            'creator': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
        }
```

Has anyone faced this issue before? What could be the solution? Any help is greatly appreciated. Have been trying this for the past three days with no luck. Tastypie documentations are not that great.

Comment: Could you please paste the full traceback ?

Comment: Thank you kgr. I just got it resolved. I changed the relation in the TaskResource    from fields.fields.ForeignKey('task.api.UserResource','creator',related_name='tasks')    to     fields.ToOneField('challenge.api.UserResource','creator',full=True)

Comment: I didn't help much, but I'm glad you got it sorted out :)